# WinSCP from Windows 2000 server to Windows 2016 OpenSSH server refuses to start shell/command

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2016, scp, windows-server-2000, winscp

I have a Windows 2000 server that I installed WinSCP 4.4.0 on, and a Windows 2016 server that I installed an OpenSSH server on.

I can ssh into the Windows 2016 server fine from Linux, as well as from the Windows 2000 server using PuTTY. I can also run WinSCP and connect to the Windows 2016 server using SFTP. However when I try connecting with WinSCP using the SCP protocol, I get that error about not being able to start a shell/command.

Here is the full log on the Windows 2000 side:

```
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 WinSCP Version 4.4.0 (Build 1904) (OS 5.0.2195 Service Pack 4)
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Configuration: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Local account: Win2000_host\root
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Login time: Tuesday, May 21, 2019 3:22:37 PM
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Session name: mssql conversion (Modified stored session)
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Host name: <win2016_ip> (Port: 22)
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 User name: my_user (Password: Yes, Key file: Yes)
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Tunnel: No
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Transfer Protocol: SCP
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Ping type: -, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Proxy: none
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Bypass authentication: No
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: 
No
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Ciphers: aes,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 SSH Bugs: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 SFTP Bugs: A,A
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Yes
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Shell: default
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 EOL: 0, UTF: 2
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Local directory: F:\bk\development, Remote directory: 
/C:/Users/my_user/Downloads, Update: No, Cache: Yes
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 DST mode: 1
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Looking up host "<win2016_ip>"
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.406 Connecting to <win2016_ip> port 22
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.515 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.9
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.515 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.515 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_4.4
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.578 Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.578 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.875 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.875 ssh-rsa 2048 3d:00:8f:80:66:c8:d9:68:46:fe:3f:4d:a2:f7:bc:c2
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.875 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.875 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.875 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2019-05-21 15:22:37.875 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.000 Reading private key file "C:\Documents and Settings\root\ssh\id_rsa.ppk"
! 2019-05-21 15:22:38.000 Using username "my_user".
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.046 Offered public key
! 2019-05-21 15:22:38.093 Server refused our key
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.093 Server refused our key
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.093 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.140 Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.140 Prompt (7, SSH password, , &Password: )
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.140 Using stored password.
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.140 Sent password
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.187 Access granted
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.390 Opened channel for session
. 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 Server refused to start a shell/command
* 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 (ESshFatal) Server refused to start a shell/command
* 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 Authentication log (see session log for details):
* 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 Using username "my_user".
* 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 Server refused our key.
* 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 
* 2019-05-21 15:22:38.531 Authentication failed.
```

I checked the event viewer on the Windows 2016 server for the OpenSSH service. This is all it said:

```
sshd: Accepted password for my_user from <win2000_ip> port 37288 ssh2
```

I'm at a loss, I am not sure what's wrong with the way I'm sshing in. There are no errors on the server side, only the client side. And there doesn't seem to be a way to disable starting a shell in WinSCP 4.4.0.

Let me know if there is any other information that may help diagnose this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have an answer to why you get this specific error (I get past that point when I try WinSCP against Windows OpenSSH server).

But even if you solve that, it's unlikely to help you. WinSCP [needs *nix-like shell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/requirements#scp). And Windows OpenSSH server does not come with one. So you will get another error, even if you solve this one.

*So the question is rather, why do you even want to use SCP, if SFTP works.*

Comment: The reason I wanted to use SCP was because SFTP is a lot slower. I ended up uninstalling the windows openssh server, and installing cygwin, with openssh. That solved the issue with the shell.

Ideally I would be able to use something even faster, and that could pick up where it left off, like rsync, but since I'm stuck using a windows 2000 server as the client that's not very easy.